# How to get text from tags, trimm, and paste to tags again in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, strip, trim

I would like to trimm text from html tags, and paste result to these tags again. It's not DOM content, only string.

```
var string = "<div class='someClass'><b>Some very long text</b></div>"
```

Wanted result is f.e.:

```
var string = "<div class='someClass'><b>Some very lon</b></div>"
```

I found library [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags), but it only gets rid off tags, but I want to keep them.

If you have any solution please let me know :)

UPDATE:

Thanks all of you for advices. There are few things to add from me: 1. I never have information about html tags, because it came from quill text editor, and I need some kind of regex. 2. In my job there is no jQuery, it's kind of 'evil' :P. 3. I'm using react, so any use of 'document' or 'window' is unwanted here :(.

Comment: if you consider to use library, why not using jquery? and use $.html() method: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) method of javascript or [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string and you want to trim some portion of text. you can use the substring/slice function of javascript.

For more refernce you can refer below links

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is exact like you showed `<div class='someClass'><b>Some very long text</b></div>`, you could do it with regex to find the text, and in the function change it how you like, shorten(*substr*)/*trim*/...:

```js
var longText ="<div class='someClass'><b>Some very long text</b></div>";

const MAX_LENGTH = 13;

// regex expression matches the structure given
var shortText = longText.replace(/(<div[^>]+><b>)([^<]+)(?=<\/b><\/div>)/gi, function(m1,m2,m3){
// m2 matches "<div class='someClass'><b>"
// m3 matches "Some very long"
return m2 + m3.substr(0, MAX_LENGTH).trim();
})
console.info(shortText)
```

> Here some documentation to the replace function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

**A "cooler" Alternative:**
If you pass the HTML Element that should be altered, to this short function `checkChildren`, all Child-Textnodes will be modified, `trim`, `substr`, ...
(it is a bit of an overkill, checking every node, if you know the final structure, but i just wanted to test it):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("test");
//define the max length of text nodes
const MAX_LENGTH = 13;

checkChildren(elem);

// check all children from parent element an limit the size of textNodes
function checkChildren(parent){
  for(var i=0; i<parent.childNodes.length;i++){
  var child = parent.childNodes[i];
    switch(child.nodeType){
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        // recursive call
        checkChildren(child);
        break;
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // modify textNode (Shorten and trim)
        child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.substr(0,MAX_LENGTH).trim(); 
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class='someClass'><b>Some very long text</b></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden tag where you manipulate the string. Something like
`<div id="tags-modifier" ></div>`
and then jquery like like

```
var string = "<div class='someClass'><b>Some very long text</b><b>Test2213213213213</b></div>"
$("#tags-modifier").html(string);
var part= 5;
$.each($('#tags-modifier *:not(:has("*"))'), function(){
    mytext=$(this).html()
    $(this).html(mytext.substring(0, part))
})
string = $("#tags-modifier").html();
```

This works even if there are multiple siblings

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/32a9exgc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.parseHTML to convert this string into dom tree. Get the `<b>` node from this dom tree and change the text with the help of substr.